# Why does geocode keep returning the wrong address but Google Maps works correctly

Tags: r, google-maps-api-3, ggmap

I'm in the New Orleans area.  When I open Google Maps in the New Orleans area and then search for "Council on Alcohol & Drug", I get the correct location with coordinates (longitude = -90.09, latitude = 29.96).

[image]

Yet, when I use the `geocode` method from ggmap, I keep getting some other coordinates not even in New Orleans.  I've tried a number of tricks to get this to work but still haven't found a solution.

```
library(ggmap)
geocode(location="Council on Alcohol & Drug") # NA NA
geocode(location="Council on Alcohol & Drug New Orleans") # NA NA
geocode(location="Council on Alcohol & Drug&components=administrative_area:Louisiana") # -91.96 30.98
geocode(location="Council on Alcohol & Drug&components=administrative_area:New Orleans") # NA NA
geocode(location="Council on Alcohol & Drug&region=New Orleans") # NA NA
```

`geocode` seems squirrely for me in general.  Any advice on getting it to behave?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Converting the "&" to "and" corrected the problem.  (Solved it as I was typing my question and figured it'd still be worth posting.)

Comment: I'm presuming the problem is that the `&` is used to separate arguments in the string passed to `geocode()`?